# MySQL trouble connecting two columns of names

Tags: mysql, data-science

I have two tables that I'm trying to connect. One table is called *2019projections* and the other is called *2019actualstat*. I want to connect the two by names. I'm 99% sure every name that is in *2019actualstat* is in *2019projections*, but not every name in *2019actualstat* is in *2019projections*. The latter has alot more names, but most of them are useless.

- I've tried left join and right join.
- I've tried select distinct
- I gave a shot at exists

This is what I have so far:

```
USE Fantasyfootball;
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM 2019actualstat;
    LEFT JOIN 2019projections ON 
2019actualstat.Player = 
2019projections.first_last;
```

It's giving me the **1064 error**, but I think it has to do with the *2019projections* table having more records.

> 21:27:26  LEFT JOIN 2019projections ON 2019actualstat.Player =
>   2019projections.first_last    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN 2019projections ON
>   2019actualstat.Player = 2019projections.first_last' at line 1 0.00071
>   sec

`2019projections.first_last` is a `varchar(50)` and `2019actualstat.player` is text

PS: I have the .csv files which I'm not sure how to post, but I would be happy to send them both.

Comment: Can you include the error you are seeing as part of your question? What is the type of each column? Joining two columns shouldn't generate an error, unless you're making a mistake in how you compare the columns.

Comment: 21:27:26 LEFT JOIN 2019projections ON 2019actualstat.Player = 2019projections.first_last Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN 2019projections ON 2019actualstat.Player = 2019projections.first_last' at line 1 0.00071 sec

Comment: Please include as part of your question, instead of a comment. That way your question reads easily. A quick google reveals that "The MySQL error 1064 is a syntax error, meaning that the MySQL is unable to understand the command you are issuing, because your command is not a valid one within the Structured Query Language or SQL."

Comment: Have you tried adding a `SELECT columns`? The 1064 means "Syntax error" and I think your syntax error is a `FROM` without a preceding `SELECT`. There also shouldn't be a semi-colon after the `FROM`. I think you want something like `SELECT {columns} FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON {join condition} ;`

Comment: Ah the error is because one is text and one is a varchar?

Comment: Ah, no. The error is because proper SQL starts with SELECT not FROM. And there is no semi-colon between the FROM clause and the LEFT JOIN clause.

Comment: Sorry. The Select Distinct got cut out. I removed the ; between From and Left Join and now it's giving me a 1146 error. I will try to work on it more. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Well as long as you have the correct syntax, and the question is edited to contain the correct syntax, you should re-edit your question with your latest updates. Otherwise, people are going to visit this page and scratch their heads wondering what's wrong with your example as currently posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `select` list, and have a redundant (wrong) semicolon at the end of the `from` clause:

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM      2019actualstat
LEFT JOIN 2019projections ON 2019actualstat.Player = 2019projections.first_last;
```

Comment: Correct answer. Everybody, you can go home now.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!